# Unexpected Identifier Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, json, html

I'm not sure why my code won't run.

**Here is my JavaScript code:**

```
fuction update(id, value){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }else{
            document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=
                                "AJAX Failed: " + xmlhttp.status;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","updatevis.php?id="+id+"&value="+value);
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML="Sending Ajax Request";
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**This is my HTML form code:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="visible" id="'.$id.'" checked="'.$checked.'" onchange="update('.$id.', '.$visible.')" />
```

The `id` would be anything from 1-whatever its auto increment, visible is a `int`, either 1 or 0 Checked is just my code to have it start checked or not

I have already run this code through chrome and Firefox, chrome gave my two errors a Unexpected identifier on line 5 (the line where I define the function) and a `ReferenceError` saying the function is not defined, on line 30 (the checkbox one)

Comment: "This is my HTML form code" — No that is some (presumably) PHP that generates HTML. Since we don't know what the variables contain, it isn't even the complex code to generate that HTML. Please show actual HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've miss-spelt `function` on the first line as `fuction`. Change this and everything should work as expected.

Comment: Well, guess who feels like a complete moron now, thanks for the response

Comment: @user1879546 No worries, don't feel bad it can happen to anyone!